# Trying to set a value by referencing separate json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Im trying to separate out the functionality of my model and the data so ive created a separate json file with a basic table

when my model builds it creates an object and i need it to create a value in it based on a value  coming in:

```
{
"1":"apple",
"2":"banana",
"3":"orange",
"4":"grape"
}

  async save (xmlOrder) {
    let customerOrder = {
      ID: xmlOrder.ID,
      Name: xmlOrder.Name ,
      ItemCode: xmlOrder.ItemCode ,
      Fruit: (This set by referencing the json, based on the Item code coming in above)enter code here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import that json object in file where you're having your model, than based on input to function you can get value out of object.

```js
let obj = {"1":"apple","2":"banana","3":"orange","4":"grape"}

function save (xmlOrder) {
  let customerOrder = {
     ID: xmlOrder.ID,
     Name: xmlOrder.Name ,
     ItemCode: xmlOrder.ItemCode ,
     Fruit: obj[xmlOrder.ItemCode] || 'Not in list',
   }
 return customerOrder
}

console.log(save({ID:33,Name:'Name',ItemCode:'2'}))
console.log(save({ID:303,Name:'Name1',ItemCode:'21'}))
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i need the Fruit to be assigned based on the item code. console.log(save({ID:33,Name:'Name',ItemCode:'2',Fruit:'banana'}))

Comment: @Dizz it is assigned by Itemcode only in the above answer.